# installing sivp-0.5.1 in scilab (version 5.4.1)

Tags: installation, scilab

I am new to scilab. I have a image compression project to make, which shows how SVD can be used in reducing the memory usage of the system by compressing the image. For this i need to install SVIP on Scilab. I downloaded SVIP version as mentioned in the question and followed whats given in the "Readme" file . But when i gave the following command :

cd C:/SCILAB/contrib/sivp-0.5.1 , it gave the error as :

!--error 77 
cd: Wrong number of input argument(s): 0 to 1 expected.

can anyone please help whats wrong and how i can rectify it plz ... i couldnt get much info about it on the net... a big thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are providing more than 1 input argument, my guess is that placing the path between single quotation marks could solve it.